# JAVA Applet issue in IE 11

Tags: java, applet

i am facing the issue while loading applet in IE11. i have enabled both the java plugins(Tools>Manage add-ons)(java(tm) Plug-In in SSV helper,java(tm) Plug-In 2 in SSV helper), even checked the"Enable java content in browser"(Java Control Panel> security) and checked all the custom level settings in browser tools>Internet options>Security>Custom Level.
Even The grey space where applet used to load is not coming,please suggest.Below are my system configuration.
Windows 7/IE11/JAVA 8/64 bit.

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

IE only support 32-bit Java.  Visit https://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp with IE, and click "Verify Java version", follow the steps to install the JRE.